# migrating spring + tomcat webapp from mac to ubuntu

Tags: spring, macos, hibernate, tomcat, ubuntu

I have been working on a webapp using ExtJs 5, Spring 4.1.5, and Hibernate 4.3.x in a Tomcat 8.0.20 server in OSX Yosemite. All is well and good until I was required to deploy said application in Ubuntu 14.10.

Tomcat works fine, but when I copy the deployed app folder (tomcat/webapps/app) from Mac to Ubuntu, my app fails to start and throws an exception:

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

I googled it (said something to do with incompatibility) and tried to recompile my java source code in Ubuntu, but to no avail.

I am under the impression that java is portable between platforms. Why does this happen? How can I migrate my webapp? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're supposed to deploy the application artifact (i.e. the WAR file, e.g. app.war), not copy the entire exploded webapps/app/ folder. You didn't mention anything about Java version, it's possible there's a mismatch.

Comment: @kryger app is still in development, so it's easier to have javascript files edited on the fly. mac java version is 7u45, ubuntu is open jdk 7u79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super late answer: this was solved by removing hidden classes created by Unix(OSX)